# Implement SSO (using LDAP) in my NodeJs project

Tags: node.js, kerberos

I want to implement SSO (using LDAP) in my NodeJs project and I am considering my options. I have used Kerberos in my Spring Boot project but I am not sure if Kerberos is well supported in the NodeJs community. If not, then please suggest a better alternative to Kerberos.